# hammer.js swipe right next page

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I want to swipe right for next page and swipe right for previous page, I searched long time for ways to do, nothing seems to work

hammer.js seems the most promising

```js
hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer. });
```

the below suggested script doen't seem to work, any other suggestions?

Comment: 67% of internet use comes from mobile devices and I can't find a simple way to swipe to go to the next page, this should be a standard feature and yet there is no examples of such that actually work

Answer (score 0):

```
const hammerTime = new Hammer(someElement)
hammerTime.on('swipeleft swiperight', (event) => {
  switch(event.type) {
    case 'swipeleft': 
      window.location.href = "https://someurl.com"
      break
    case 'swiperight':
      window.location.href = "https://someotherurl.com"
      break
  }
})
```

or

```
hammerTime.on('swipeleft', (event) => {
  window.location.href = "https://someurl.com"
})
hammerTime.on('swiperight', (event) => {
  window.location.href = "https://someotherurl.com"
})
```

Comment: Hmmm...`open` would have to be a pre-defined function. In absence of that being the case, you can just use `window.location.href` (sample edited to reflect this).

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hammer-swipe-newurl

I made site on glitch

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @RyanHerter Works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/0p5tgcsn/

Answer (score 0):

I may have found one solution which has worked for my case.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var hammertime = Hammer(el);
    hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL });
    /* the magic... */
    hammertime.on('swipe', function(ev) {
        var direction = '';
     switch(ev.direction) {
         case Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT:
         var right = document.querySelector('.right');
         var href_right = right.getAttribute('href');
         document.location.href=href_right;
         break;
         case Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT:
         var left = document.querySelector('.left');
         var href_left = left.getAttribute('href');
         document.location.href=href_left;
         break;
         }

    });
}, false);
```

This js script empowered by Hammer is getting the direction of the swipe gesture and then is retrieving the class of the  element which corresponds to get its attribute href and redirect the user to it.

```html
<div class="thumb-first">
<!-- Swipe -->
<div class="swipe">
 <a class="left" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><span></span></a>
 <a class="active" href="#"><span></span></a>
 <a class="right" href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps !